# Unable to delete a file with DeleteAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, delete-file

I'm working in VS2012, WinRT and C#.

I'm trying to delete some files after decompressing them. I'm getting an "Access is denied" error. If I stop the app and re-start it the same code works fine so it appears there is a handle still attached.

If I don't call the unZipFile method, I can delete the files.

Is there a definitive way to release a file? I've set it to null (file = null;) before the call to delete.

Here's the block of code that calls the unzip method:

```
    StorageFile file = await CreateOutputFile(fileName, path);

        MemoryStream theMemStream = new MemoryStream();

        theMemStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, bytes);

        await theMemStream.FlushAsync();
        theMemStream.Dispose();

        var result = await unZipFile(file, path);

        file = null;
```

Here's the unZipFile method:

```
        private async Task<string> unZipFile(StorageFile file, string path)
        {

        StorageFolder sf = await GetOutputFolder(path);

    using (var zipStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        using (MemoryStream zipMemoryStream = new MemoryStream((int)zipStream.Length))
        {

            await zipStream.CopyToAsync(zipMemoryStream);

            try
            {
                var archive = SharpCompress.Archive.ArchiveFactory.Open(file.Path);

                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    entry.WriteTo(zipMemoryStream);

                    Stream fileData = entry.OpenEntryStream();

                    StorageFile outputFile = await sf.CreateFileAsync(entry.FilePath, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                    using (Stream outputFileStream = await outputFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                    {
                        await fileData.CopyToAsync(outputFileStream);
                        await outputFileStream.FlushAsync();
                        outputFileStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                archive = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new IOException("Error writing decompressed output file: " + ex.Message);
            }

            await zipStream.FlushAsync();
            zipStream.Dispose();

            await zipMemoryStream.FlushAsync();
            zipMemoryStream.Dispose();
        }
    }

    return "success";
}
```

Here's the delete method. This is called for each file after decompression:

```
private async Task<string> deleteFile(string path, string filename)
{
    StorageFolder folder = await GetOutputFolder(path);

    var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.Name == filename)
                    await file.DeleteAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On what file do you get the exception, the extracted files or the zip archive itself?

If the latter is the case, `ArchiveFactory.Open()` returns an `IArchive` which inherits `IDisposable`, so you should wrap `var archive = SharpCompress.Archive.ArchiveFactory.Open(file.Path);` in a `using` block so it gets disposed after use.

Comment: That was it! Great catch. I'd give you a click but it won't let me because I don't have enough points yet. I will as soon as I can.